# Visiting my mother in the US; she has overstayed her visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, overstaying, minors

My mother and I went to the United States last year. But after a month, I went home to my country in the Philippines and my mother overstayed her visa, because she was diagnosed with cancer and she ran out of time extending her stay, because of her immediate treatment. Now, one year later, I'm planning to visit my mother again and bring her home back to my country.

1. Can this situation affect my ability to enter the US? what questions would I expect and is it possible to get in the United States?
2. I'm only 17 years old, and I researched that I need a letter of consent from my parents allowing me to travel to United States (which is currently taken care of) and my question is does the letter affect my questions in the port of entry?
3. Does the DHS know that my mother overstayed and can the POE officer look that up in their database?

I know there is a high chance that I will be denied in the port of entry, but I'm looking forward to have hope that I can see my mother again.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this situation affect my ability to enter the US?

Yes it can and likely will. Although individuals are supposedly evaluated on their own merits, having a close family member as an overstayer **can** negatively impact your application, especially since you are a minor who traveled there with her.

> what questions would I expect and is it possible to get in the United
>   States?

Too broad to answer. Yes it is **possible** however possible does not ascribe any particular probability of success.

> I'm only 17 years old, and I researched that I need a letter of
>   consent from my parents allowing me to travel to United States (which
>   is currently taken care of) and my question is does the letter affect
>   my questions in the port of entry?

Definitely, the fact that you are a minor opens up its own can of worms or considerations and questions. Why is a minor undertaking this task, are there not other adults like her husband, siblings, etc? Why can't the people she is staying with in the USA do that, etc.

> Does the DHS know that my mother overstayed and can the POE officer
>   look that up in their database?

Very likely and yes. It almost definitely is in the records of course however without checking the immigration officer would not know and they would only check if they have a reason.

### TL:DR

Your mothers cancer is not a very compelling reason to be given a visa to **bring her back**. Last year we sent a member of our community back home to die of cancer. He was not ambulatory and was transported in a wheelchair and the airline took over from check in. Airlines do that all the time for solo travelers so your mothers case is neither novel nor compelling enough to change the status quo.